# Feedback pop-up when downvoting an example should require submit action

Tags: feature-request, documentation, user-interface

I've just downvoted an example in the documentation. A pop-up came up and asked me to leave feedback. There were choices: "Not helpful", a couple of other things, and "Other".

I hadn't decided what to choose at first, so I selected "Other", and saw a text box asking for more detail. Because I didn't know what the other sub-options would be, I went back to select "Not helpful".

To my surprise, selecting the "Not helpful" radio button was enough to validate my selection straight away, and the pop-up disappeared. I would generally expect some form of Save/Submit button when making a selection amongst radio buttons, especially when you don't have the opportunity to go back.